# Javascript code replacing page content when run from the address bar

Tags: javascript

For the hell of it, I decided to write

```
for(var i =0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("p").length;i++){
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].style.textTransform = "uppercase";
}
```

I was going to send this to someone as a joke. It's supposed to make all the text on the page uppercase.

What I don't understand is: Why does the entire content of the page get replaced with the word "uppercase" when I run this from the address bar?

```
javascript:for(var i =0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("p").length;i++){ document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].style.textTransform = "uppercase"; }
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aCjxT.png) in the current version of Chrome on OS X Lion.

Comment: -1 for a lack of information. More information about the intended results or a screenshot of the output would be desired.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks, Thanks, that's what I was hoping for, but it's not working.

Comment: That loop is very inefficient:  every time around, it'll search the page for `<p>` elements all over again, twice.  Do the `getElementsByTagName()` once and store it in a variable, and use the variable in the loop.

Comment: The answer has been deleted for some reason, but add `void(0)` to the end of your code and it will work in the address bar without replacing the content of the screen with the word "uppercase".

Comment: lol @ this question and Jeremy's answer

Comment: Thanks!! Exactly what I needed. What does `void(0)` do?

Comment: @Wyzard, Yeah, I figured I would test it before making it efficient...

Comment: @user828584: I think the downvotes could have been avoided if you had specified that the code works normally, without using the address bar. Your question was simply unclear.

Comment: @Wesley: I agree.. but Jeremy's answer still made me laugh and someone had to win

Comment: @user828584: Some browsers display the value of the code you enter, instead of just running it. `void(0)` has no value, so the browser doesn't try to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to paste it in the address bar try:

```
javascript:(function(){
               for(var p=document.getElementsByTagName("p"),n=p.length; n--;){
                  p[n].style.textTransform = "uppercase";
               }
           })()
```

Not exactly sure why it didn't work from address bar (at least in Chrome), but it will if you call it from a function.  There could be a scoping issue, or it could have something to do with the `for` construct.  Regardless, if you wrap it in an anonymous function call, it'll work.

Comment: For me, no matter what, Chrome strips the `javascript:` bit and redirects to a Google search of the code.

Comment: Yeah, you have to type in the `javascript:` portion again.  I think that's Chrome security at work.  Actually, no, it's how Chrome works, it drops the protocol off webpages too (eg `http://www.ebay.com` becomes `www.ebay.com`)

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript:for(var i =0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("p").length;i++){ document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].style.textTransform = "capitalize";void(0);}
```

Capitalize all words within paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

If your whole document is made of `p` tags, then you are making everything in those tags `uppercase`.

See this http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Y6nn2/

What did you want to happen?

Comment: Yeah, that. I was going to send it to someone and have them paste it in the address bar as a joke, but I guess not...